# Angular2: Use DomSanitizer with HTML and STYLE

Tags: angular, angular-dom-sanitizer

I use angular 2.1.2, and I want to use sanitize method to prevent XSS/CSRF attacks.

I implemented: 
`this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, this.content)`

The html file have html, style, javascript. So this method will unwrap the style and javascript.

But I just only want unwrap for javascript and skip html and style.
So, any solution for me to implement this issue.

HTML before sanitation

```
<html>
  <head><style>h2 {color: #FFFF7C}</style>
    <script>alert("hi")</script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <h2>HTML Content</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Result after sanitation:

```
//HTML content: "&#10; h2 {color: #FFFF7C}&#10; alert(&#34;hi&#34;)&#10; &#10; &#10; <h2>HTML Content</h2>&#10; &#10;"

//HTML content view:
h2 {color: #FFFF7C} alert("hi")
HTML Content
```

Result expect:

```
alert("hi")
HTML Content //I expect this line will be applied the color: #FFFF7C
```

Comment: what do you mean by `html, style, javascript`? show an example of HTML before sanitation and how you want it to look after sanitation

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com, I just update my question, please view again, thanks

Comment: _make this script doesn't work_ - `sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML` will just remove `<script>` so the following `script>alert("hi")</script>` will be `alert("hi")`. It doesn't touch `style` tag.

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com, currently the result is `"&#10;  h2 {color: #FFFF7C}&#10;    alert(&#34;hi&#34;)&#10;    &#10;  &#10;    <h2>HTML Content</h2>&#10;  &#10;"`. The `style` tag is also unwrap. I just update post.

Comment: And I'm using angular 2.1.2

Comment: I see, add that information to the post, and Angular version as well

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com, I updated, thanks.

Comment: Any solution for me :(

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar how sanitizer works in v2. maybe create a demo and post it here